# I am trying to install my rails app onto a Ubuntu 10.04 box running in Vagrant (Virtualbox). I'm running into the following errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, ubuntu-10.04, capybara-webkit

### Issue

I am trying to install my rails app onto a Ubuntu 10.04 box running as a guest on Vagrant (Virtualbox). I'm running into the below errors with devise and capybara-webkit.

The strange thing is that it installs perfectly with my same Gemfile.lock on Heroku cedar that has the same configuration as my Ubuntu server.

### Errors

1. `undefined method 'skip_session_storage' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)` with installed devise (1.5.2) on `rails server` startup.
2. `An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.0.0) with bundler`

   `Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

The second seems to be related to QT.

### My configuration

- Vagrant 1.2.4
- Virtualbox 4.2.16x
- Ubuntu 10.04
- Postgres 9.2
- QT 4.8.5 for capybara support
- Redis version 1.2.0
- Rbenv 0.4.0-54
- Ruby 1.9.3-p392
- Gem 1.8.23
- Bundler 1.3.5
- Rails 3.2.10
- capybara-webkit 1.0.0

Comment: I got this working. I managed to fix the devise problem by upgrading to the latest version in my Gemfile. Still having issues with capybara-webkit

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of devise 3.0 fixes my devise errors. I am going to close this in favor of breaking out the second capybara error at [Problems installing capybara-webkit 1.0.0 in Rails 3.2.10 on Ubuntu 10.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18804801/501549)