# Problems installing capybara-webkit 1.0.0 in Rails 3.2.10 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara-webkit

### Issue

I am unable to get Capybara-webkit 1.0.0 to install into my Rails 3.2.10 project.

When I run `bundle install` I get the following errors.

Also when I roll capybara-webkit back to version `0.12.1` (May 30, 2012) it installs fine.

Note: I am having this same problem on both OSX 10.8 and Ubuntu 10.04

### Errors

`An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.0.0) with bundler`

`Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

### Thoughts

- It seems to be related to QT even though I have the recommended 4.8.5 installed

### My configuration

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Postgres 9.2
- QT 4.8.5 for capybara support
- Redis version 1.2.0
- Rbenv 0.4.0-54
- Ruby 1.9.3-p392
- Gem 1.8.23
- Bundler 1.3.5
- Rails 3.2.10
- capybara-webkit 1.0.0

#### My Gemfile

Here is the Gemfile:

```bash
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem "builder"
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'rails', '3.2.10'
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.2.3"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'

gem 'appsignal'
gem 'appsignal-redis'
gem 'skylight'
gem "rollbar", "~> 0.10.12"
gem 'exceptional'

gem 'forem', :git => "git://github.com/radar/forem.git"
gem 'forem-postgres-search', :git=>"git://github.com/jgadbois/forem-postgres-search.git"
gem 'forem-theme-base', :path=>'vendor/gems/forem-theme-wt'
gem 'forem-markdown_formatter', :git => "git://github.com/jgadbois/forem-markdown_formatter.git"

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'dalli', :git=>'git://github.com/mperham/dalli.git'
  gem 'rpm_contrib'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'memcachier'
end

group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 3.0"
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'rspec-rails', ">= 2.14"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard-rspec', "~> 2.5"
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'rack-livereload'
end

gem 'heroku', ">= 2.40"
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-web'
gem "hiredis", "~> 0.4.0"
gem "redis", "~> 3.0", :require => ["redis/connection/hiredis", "redis"]
gem 'resque_mailer'
gem "hirefire-resource"
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-encryptable'
gem "omniauth-facebook"

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem "rake", '0.9.2.2'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 4.0.10'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "simple-navigation"
gem 'ransack'
gem 'amazon-product-advertising-api'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem "activemerchant", :git => 'git://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant.git'#:git => 'git://github.com/jgadbois/active_merchant.git'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'profanity_filter'

source "http://gems.github.com"
gem "feedzirra"
gem "grackle"
gem "rmagick"
gem 'hominid'

gem "letter_opener", :group => :development

gem 'rack-contrib'
gem 'soulmate', :require => 'soulmate/server', :github => 'jgadbois/soulmate'

gem 'wicked_pdf', :git => 'git://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf.git'
gem 'dynamic_form'

gem "SystemTimer", :require => "system_timer", :platforms => :ruby_18
gem "rack-timeout"

gem 'pusher'
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'roadie' 
gem 'rails_autolink' 
gem 'leaderboard', "~> 2.2.0"
gem 'wicked'
gem 'rack-rewrite'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'koala'
gem 'health_graph'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'mandrill-api', '>= 1.0.41'
gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.0"
gem "heroku-api"
gem "bust_rails_etags"
gem 'cache_digests'

gem 'activerecord-postgres-hstore'
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste your Gemfile here?

Comment: Hello Tyler my Gemfile is above.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to install Qt. Try these instructions: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Answer (score 0):

That's a heck of a lot of gems.  First thing to try is to make sure you have the necessary version of Capybara (greater than 2.0.2):

```
gem 'capybara', '>= 2.0.2'
```

If that doesn't help, try commenting out blocks of your included gems until the gemfile will build.  Once it does, you can try uncommenting different gems until it fails again.  Then you will at least know where the conflict is so that you can try to resolve it.  More info on `capybara-webkit` dependencies here: http://rubygems.org/gems/capybara-webkit

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the libraries needed to compile the gem:

```
# ubuntu    
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```